# In The Umbrella Academy who does Number 5 owe a debt to?

Tags: dark-horse-comics, the-umbrella-academy

In *The Umbrella Academy* in the episode "The Day That Wasn't" number five says:

> I do owe a debt, but not to you.

Is it specified in the comics who he was referring to?

Comment: Possibly a useful reference: https://comicvine.gamespot.com/the-boy/4005-60400/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number Five's arc in this episode roughly follows [*The Umbrella Academy: Dallas* issue 3, "Television, Or Are You There, God? It's Me, Klaus"](https://umbrellaacademy.fandom.com/wiki/The_Umbrella_Academy:_Dallas_3), but I don't believe the answer really exists there since the adaptation is a bit different.

Simply put, Number Five owes the debt to his family, and the episode is him setting things up to come back to help them avert the apocalypse.

Comment: Having re-read the comic for the question, I can confirm the answer is not in the comics. It begins to perhaps tell us, but then Five is interrupted by the monocle.